# Read Transactions (arules) has less items than R Data Frame?

Tags: r, encoding, associations, apriori, arules

I have a R DataFrame that consists of the columns `ID` and `Items`. If I filter for e.g. a certain term like 'RABBIT NIGHT LIGHT' I get 178 records.
But if I read in the data with read.transactions(), I only get 167 records for the term. What is the reason for this and how can I correct it? I suspect that there is an encoding problem.
You can download my dataset [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1w1OunMHBSfdT8FpWI0x_B5bd-jg2Oa73/view?usp=sharing).

MWE:

```
df <- read.csv(file = 'orders.csv', header = TRUE, sep = ",", strip.white = TRUE)
dim(df[df$Items == 'RABBIT NIGHT LIGHT',])
>Output: 178, 2

write.csv(df, "_transactions.csv", row.names=FALSE)
transactions <- read.transactions(
        file = "_transactions.csv",
        format = "single",
        sep = ",",
        cols=c("Id","Items"),
        rm.duplicates = T,
        header = TRUE
)

summary(transactions)

>Output: 167 Items for RABBIT NIGHT LIGHT
```

How can the difference be explained and what might be a fix to this?

Comment: There are duplicates, e.g. `580305,RABBIT NIGHT LIGHT` is there four times (4×) in `orders.csv`…

Comment: you are right. Obviously read transactions removes duplicates automatically.